# How to get 'fair combination' from an array of n elements?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math, combinations

Using `combination` method on Ruby,

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].combination(2).to_a
#=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 3],
#    [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6],
#    [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6]]
```

we can get a 2-dimensional array having 15 (6C2) elements.

I would like to create a `fair_combination` method that returns an array like this:

```
arr = [[1, 2], [3, 5], [4, 6],
       [3, 4], [5, 1], [6, 2],
       [5, 6], [1, 3], [2, 4],
       [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 1],
       [1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

So that every three sub-arrays (half of 6) contain all the given elements:

```
arr.each_slice(3).map { |a| a.flatten.sort }
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
#    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
#    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
#    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
#    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

This makes it kind of "fair", by using as different elements as possible as arrays go on.

To make it more general, what it needs to satisfy is as follows:

(1) As you follow the arrays from start and count how many times each number appears, at any point it should be as flat as possible;

```
(1..7).to_a.fair_combination(3)
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 1, 4], [2, 5, 3], [6, 7, 2], ...]
```

The first 7 numbers make [1,2,...,7] and so do the following 7 numbers.

(2) Once number A comes in the same array with B, A does not want to be in the same array with B if possible.

```
(1..10).to_a.fair_combination(4)
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 1, 5], [2, 6, 9, 3], [4, 7, 10, 8], ...]
```

Is there any good algorithm that creates a "fair combination" like this ?

Comment: I hate being that guy, but what have you *tried*?

Comment: @NickZuber
Thank you for your comment. Managed to create a sort of equivalent of fair_combination(2); https://gist.github.com/honake/b685811d7644c563cd26a620274a75e6
but does not work quite well & could not make it more general.

Answer (score 1):

It's not guaranteed to give the *best* solution, but it gives a good enough one.

At each step, it chooses a minimal subpool which is the set of items of minimal height, for which there is still a combination to choose from (height is the number of times the items have been used before).

For instance, let the enumerator be

```
my_enum = FairPermuter.new('abcdef'.chars, 4).each
```

The first iteration may return

```
my_enum.next  # => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

At this point those letters have height 1, but there is not enough letters of height 0 to make a combination, so take just all of them for the next:

```
my_enum.next  # => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'] for instance
```

Now the heights are `2` for `a`, `b` and `c`, `1` for `d` and `e`, and `0` for `f`, and still the optimal pool is the full initial set.

So this is not really optimized for combinations of large size. On the other side, if the size of the combination is at most half of the size of the initial set, then the algorithm is pretty decent.

```
class FairPermuter
  def initialize(pool, size)
    @pool = pool
    @size = size
    @all = Array(pool).combination(size)
    @used = []
    @counts = Hash.new(0)
    @max_count = 0
  end

  def find_valid_combination
    [*0..@max_count].each do |height|
      candidates = @pool.select { |item| @counts[item] <= height }
      next if candidates.size < @size
      cand_comb = [*candidates.combination(@size)] - @used
      comb = cand_comb.sample
      return comb if comb
    end
    nil
  end

  def each
    return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?
    while combination = find_valid_combination
      @used << combination
      combination.each { |k| @counts[k] += 1 }
      @max_count = @counts.values.max
      yield combination
      return if @used.size >= [*1..@pool.size].inject(1, :*)
    end
  end
end
```

Results for fair combinations of 4 over 6

```
[[1, 2, 4, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 5],
 [2, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 3, 5, 6],
 [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 6], [2, 3, 4, 6], [1, 2, 5, 6],
 [1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Results of fair combination of 2 over 6

```
[[4, 6], [1, 3], [2, 5],
 [3, 5], [1, 4], [2, 6],
 [4, 5], [3, 6], [1, 2],
 [2, 3], [5, 6], [1, 6],
 [3, 4], [1, 5], [2, 4]]
```

Results of fair combinations of 2 over 5

```
[[4, 5], [2, 3], [3, 5],
 [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 5],
 [2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 3],
 [2, 5]]
```

Time to get combinations of 5 over 12:

```
        1.19 real         1.15 user         0.03 sys
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. It is definitely good algorithm. I think I am going to revise it to deal with the problem when the size of the array is not large enough.

Comment: By the way, I'm pretty sure that there is no easy way to have any algorithm, even in the restricted case of exact split combinations (like combinations of 2 over 6) when the split is not half of the whole array, without using full backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

Naïve implementation would be:

```
class Integer
  # naïve factorial implementation; no checks
  def !
    (1..self).inject(:*)
  end
end

class Range
  # constant Proc instance for tests; not needed
  C_N_R = -> (n, r) { n.! / ( r.! * (n - r).! ) }

  def fair_combination(n)
    to_a.permutation
        .map { |a| a.each_slice(n).to_a }
        .each_with_object([]) do |e, memo|
          e.map!(&:sort)
          memo << e if memo.all? { |me| (me & e).empty? }
        end
  end
end

▶ (1..6).fair_combination(2)
#⇒ [
#    [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]],
#    [[1, 3], [2, 5], [4, 6]],
#    [[1, 4], [2, 6], [3, 5]],
#    [[1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 6]],
#    [[1, 6], [2, 3], [4, 5]]]
▶ (1..6).fair_combination(3)
#⇒ [
#    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
#    [[1, 2, 4], [3, 5, 6]],
#    [[1, 2, 5], [3, 4, 6]],
#    [[1, 2, 6], [3, 4, 5]],
#    [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 6]],
#    [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]],
#    [[1, 3, 6], [2, 4, 5]],
#    [[1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 6]],
#    [[1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 5]],
#    [[1, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4]]]
▶ Range::C_N_R[6, 3]
#⇒ 20
```

Frankly, I do not understand how this function should behave for `10` and `4`, but anyway this implementation is too memory consuming to work properly on big ranges (on my machine it gets stuck on ranges of size > 8.)

To adjust this to more robust solution one needs to get rid of `permutation` there in favor of “smart concatenate permuted arrays.”

Hope this is good for starters.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am terribly sorry but I should have specified the conditions. Just specifically described the requirements this method should satisfy. But seemingly as long as the size of the input array (eg. 12) can be divided by the argument (eg. 2,3,4,6) your algorithm works awesome. I think I can start re-thinking starting from your code. Cheers.